# Is it possible to stub ActiveRecord's save method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, factory-bot, minitest

It seems like a fair bit of slowness in rails testing comes from communicating with the database. I've started replacing some tests where I call FactoryBot's `create` and `build` methods with `build_stubbed`. However, some tests involve testing callbacks and some even involve testing how multiple callbacks interact with each other.

I started searching around to see if anyone built a library that stubs the save method, but couldn't find anything. I'm picturing something that would call all the callback methods in the correct order as well as setting all the Active Model Dirty records correctly. Things like validating uniqueness and any ActiveRecord queries in callbacks would have to be manually stubbed out I guess in order to not talk with the database.

Are there any tools that already have this feature? Or is it not valuable because it ultimately won't have much of a speed impact if you're performing all those actions anyway. Is there anything I'm not considering regarding stubbing the save method?

Comment: i think this is a good idea. Maybe you can just change the database out to [nulldb](https://github.com/nulldb/nulldb). Probably there's a way to do this at runtime so you can use it only on certain tests.

Comment: Did you tried to run tests with "in-memory" database? Then you don't need to "talk" to database, everything will be executed in a memory.

Comment: @JonF Yes, like what Fabio has said, you can change it to "in-memory" db. We did this in one of our projects. This, in conjuction with [parallel_tests](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests) significantly speed up our tests. To answer your concern directly though, if you are going to stub the "save" method, you'd need to take-over making sure / consider that all other things would still work: in particular databases sometimes raise DB-related errors such as constraints and uniqueness stuff, or that the SQL query should be a correcty SQL string.

Comment: ...which if you mock the `save` method without considering these, it inadvertently makes your testing suite brittle (though instantly fast!), because you won't be able to catch / resolve errors, if they would exist, as your tests would have instead passed. If you understand the risks and possible gains, you can decide this over with your team. Personally, I'm interested if you are gonna make this feature of yours a gem, because I can make use of this in specific very heavy-db-related specs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it *impossible* to stub out the database when testing a Rails application? No, but it's practically infeasible.

The closest I'm aware of is running Rails on an in-memory SQLite instance.

Some reasons as to why:

- `save` is only one of many, many different ways to access the database in Rails
- ActiveRecord by design tightly couples your domain models with data persistence, making it difficult to stub only persistence
- SQL/RDBMS are magnificent abstractions for what they can do, it would be incredibly difficult to build a worthy mock to stub it with

I have heard of a few projects that sought to address those reasons above with big deviations from the common way Rails applications are often built:

- Use alternative objects for domain models instead of ActiveRecord, and only use AR in an extremely controlled and constrained way.
- Avoid using ActiveRecord altogether in favor of a different ORM -- one that keeps domain models decoupled from persistence

In other words, it'd require a fundamental change in the architecture and usage of a "conventional Rails app", considering how big a part ActiveRecord  normally plays.